# Package CJK Error: Invalid character code

Tags: cjk, tex-core

I am writing my PhD thesis in WinEdt 10.2 with MikTex support. My thesis needs to include cover page having chinese fonts. University thesis class has all the definitions. When i compile the main text file, it gives error:

! Package CJK Error: Invalid character code.

See the CJK package documentation for explanation. Type H for immediate help. ...

l.114 \makeCoverPage

?

Process has been terminated ...

I have included necessary CJK package in the tex file. Previously, it was running fine. Last week, i tried to install Tex Live which took too much time to install. After that this problem arrised. I have removed Tex live 2023 but the problem still persists. Please guide me how can i fix this issue? Let me know if need more information.

Looking forward to your response.

I have included CJK and CJKutf8 packages but issue still remains.

Comment: Crosspost: [LaTeX.org](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=35571).